# Is my PSQL database performance within expectations for my hardware?

Tags: database, postgresql, query-performance

I'm brand new to the concept of database administration, so I have no basis for what to expect. I am working with approximately 100GB of data in the form of five different tables. Descriptions of the data, as well as the first few rows of each file, can be found [here](https://csr.lanl.gov/data/cyber1/).

I'm currently just working with the `flows` tables in an effort to gauge performance. Here is the results from `\d flows`:

```
            Table "public.flows"
   Column   |       Type        | Modifiers 
------------+-------------------+-----------
 time       | real              | 
 duration   | real              | 
 src_comp   | character varying | 
 src_port   | character varying | 
 dest_comp  | character varying | 
 dest_port  | character varying | 
 protocol   | character varying | 
 pkt_count  | real              | 
 byte_count | real              | 
Indexes:
    "flows_dest_comp_idx" btree (dest_comp)
    "flows_dest_port_idx" btree (dest_port)
    "flows_protocol_idx" btree (protocol)
    "flows_src_comp_idx" btree (src_comp)
    "flows_src_port_idx" btree (src_port)
```

Here is the results from `EXPLAIN ANALYZE SELECT src_comp, COUNT(DISTINCT dest_comp) FROM flows GROUP BY src_comp;`, which I thought would be a relatively simple query:

```
 GroupAggregate  (cost=34749736.06..35724568.62 rows=200 width=64) (actual time=1292299.166..1621191.771 rows=11154 loops=1)
   Group Key: src_comp
   ->  Sort  (cost=34749736.06..35074679.58 rows=129977408 width=64) (actual time=1290923.435..1425515.812 rows=129977412 loops=1)
         Sort Key: src_comp
         Sort Method: external merge  Disk: 2819360kB
         ->  Seq Scan on flows  (cost=0.00..2572344.08 rows=129977408 width=64) (actual time=26.842..488541.987 rows=129977412 loops=1)
 Planning time: 6.575 ms
 Execution time: 1636290.138 ms
(8 rows)
```

If I'm interpreting this correctly (which I might not be since I'm new to PSQL), it's saying that my query would take almost 30 minutes to execute, which is much, much longer than I would expect. Even with ~130 million rows.

My computer is running with an 8th-gen i7 quad-core CPU, 16GBs of RAM, and a 2TB HDD (full specs can be found [here](https://www.cnet.com/products/dell-inspiron-17-7773-2-in-1-17-3-core-i7-8550u-16-gb-ram-2-tb-hdd/specs/)).

My questions then are: 1) is this performance to be expected, and 2) is there anything I can do to speed it up, other than buying an external SSD?

Comment: The grouping/sorting is done on disk so this will be slow. You can try to increase `work_mem` for your session in order to avoid that. But this will not reduce the time it needs to _read_ the data. Which Postgres version are you using? This should be able to use a parallel seq scan in 9.6 and higher. An index on `(src_comp, dest_comp)` might help as well

Comment: Running `SELECT version()` gives: `PostgreSQL 9.5.11 on x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc (Ubuntu 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.4) 5.4.0 20160609, 64-bit
`. I'll look into how to increase `work_mem`.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name how much of an impact on my query times should I expect from simultaneously creating an index on another table while running the query mentioned in the question? I imagine there's certainly some impact given read/write speeds of my HDD, yeah?

Comment: You should definitely look into upgrading to 10 as well to profit from parallel queries

Comment: Why doesn't your table have a  Primary Key?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I upgraded to 10 and it seems to be providing a great increase in performance. I can't isolate the results since I also upgraded to a SSD, but I was able to completely recreate the database and re-index all five tables in a fraction of the time it took me previously. Thanks for your help.

Comment: The upgrade to a SSD probably made most of the performance gain

Comment: When upgrading to SSD, you'll need to set `random_page_cost` to a lower value (approx 1.0x) tomakeindexed plans fafourite. (works only if your keys/indexes are correct (which they are not))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1 - src_comp and dest_comp, which are used by the query, are both indexed. However, they are indexed independently. If you had an index of 'src_comp, dest_comp' then there is a possibility that the database could process this all via indexes, eliminating a full table scan.

2 - src_comp and dest_comp are character varying. That is NOT a good thing for indexed fields, unless necessary. What are these values really? Numbers? IP addresses? Computer network names? If there is a relatively finite number of these items and they can be identified as they are added to the database, change them to integers that are used as foreign keys into other tables. That will make a HUGE difference in this query. If they can't be stored that way, but they at least have a definite finite length - e.g., 15 characters for IPv4 addresses in dotted quad format - then set a maximum length for the fields, which should help some.

Comment: I originally cast `src_comp` and `dest_comp` as `char(n)`, but the documentation for psql seemed to suggest that `varchar` was always the best way to go. But if I'm understanding your second suggestion correctly, you're saying that setting them as `char(n)` would be better. Is that right?

Comment: Actually, I typically use varchar(n) - the flexibility of a varchar but with a specific maximum size. But far better is if it can be somehow turned into a number. For example, unless you are using a database that specifically supports an IP Address field type, IPv4 addresses take 15 bytes as char or varchar but only 4 bytes as a 32-bit integer. Doesn't matter much for raw storage space but makes a big difference for indexes.

Comment: @brittenb: `char` is almost always a bad choice because the values are padded to the defined length. Use `text` or `varchar` in Postgres. If those columns are indeed IP addresses, the `inet` would indeed be a better choice.

Comment: @manassehkatz: there is nothing wrong with indexing `varchar` columns.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I agree. The issues are (a) assign a realistic max. length to the field and (b) if reasonable to do so, change the field to something that is smaller & indexes better, like an integer (whether as an actual value or a foreign key into another table).

Comment: I was able to recreate the database using `varchar(n)`, as well as adding multiple-column indices, and also upgraded to a SSD. All of which has seemed to have helped. I went from a 30-minute processing time for the query above to 5 minutes. Still longer than I expected, but much, much better. Thanks for your help!